# How to / best way to wait for Mongod instance to start before proceeding

Tags: python, mongodb, subprocess, pymongo

I'm trying to start a Mongod instance in Python with the following code (with some details omitted):

```
subprocess.call("mongod --fork --dbpath /asdf --port 12345", shell=True)
```

I was under the impression that subprocess waits for the process to start before returning, although this doesn't seem to be the case. For instance, if I call the following afterwards:

```
conn = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 12345)
```

I will get a connection error stating that it cannot connect:

```
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:12345: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

However, if I fire up python from within a terminal, I can connect without a problem. Additionally, I can connect if I issue a sleep command immediately after the subprocess call, although that leads to all sort of potential race conditions.

What is the best way to wait for the mongod instance to start? I could use a while loop an attempt to connect, but that seems insanely sloppy. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: subprocess waits for it to start, but mongo takes a little bit of time after it starts to bind to a port and start accepting connections. I would use a connection retry loop with a sleep.

Comment: MongoDB should be run as a daemon or a service ideally, and not started from within your application code.

Comment: I was firing up mongods as part of a testing script.... starting it from within a production application would be crazy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subprocess has started by the time `subprocess.call` returns, but it might not have started listening on a socket yet. We have to solve this problem in PyMongo's self-tests, so we wrote a `wait_for` method:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/test/high_availability/ha_tools.py#L72

The gist is, try connecting to `mongod`'s port. If it isn't listening yet, keep trying. If you've tried too many times, something's wrong (disk full, bad command-line parameters, etc.).